# How to take a screenshots?

Tags: android, screenshot

I am developing an app which is able to take screen shots and I found the following code which allows me to do that

```
Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
```

It saves the image with image name I can change it in code but I want the current date and time as the name. I tried puttinge this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

But after putting formattedDate at the place of image it does not work

Comment: what doesn't work? capturing the image or changing the filename?

Comment: i dont know its really irritating i just did this "/sdcard/"+formattedDate+".png" and it stopped taking screenshots

Comment: take a look at this blog http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.ie/2012/04/save-captured-image-to-applications.html  get the date and then where he says "new  image" just substitute formatted date

Answer (score 2):

in some cases having a ":" character in the filename is not allowed. You might want to replace it with "." or "-".

EDIT:

Try this:

```
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "\"/sdcard/"+formattedDate+".png\"").getBytes("ASCII"));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not working" ... Is there an error? or no error and no filesave?

Comment: Updated answer. On closer inspection it seems to be an issue with spaces in your shell command.

Comment: Thanks everyone it working now what i did is i changed SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(
       "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"); and then i did String st = formattedDate.toString();
     os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/"+st+".png").getBytes("ASCII"));

Comment: yes this worked because you removed the spaces. if you want spaces just encapsulate the output directory path in double quotes as i have done above and it will work.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how I can get an inverted screenshot?