# Take screenshot programmatically of the whole screen

Tags: android, keyboard, screenshot

I'm taking screenshot as below:

```
 public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(Activity activity) {  
      View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();  
      view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
      view.buildDrawingCache();  
      Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();  
      Rect rect = new Rect();  
      activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);  
      int statusBarHeight = rect.top;  
      int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();  
      int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();  
      Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, statusBarHeight, width,  
          height - statusBarHeight);  
      view.destroyDrawingCache();  
      return bitmap2;  
    }
```

But there is a Edittext in my layout. I click it and keyboard pop up, but screenshot doesn't contain keyboard using this way. How can I take screenshot programmatically also which can also capture the keyboard?

Comment: keyboard is not part your application layout. you are taking the screen shot of your layout(view). keyboard is not part of your layout. that's why you don't see it

Comment: I know this. Any ideas on how to take screenshot for the whole phone screen?

Comment: try the below answer but if you are testing on device you need to root the same. which is not right coz you can't ask users to root their device. You could try creating your own custom keyboard in your application. then use the above to take screen shot

Comment: same issue is valid for videoview on screen. when screenshot is captured using above method, videoview on screen is not included in screenshot but a blank instead of it. I need a mechanism that simulate the affect that you press some device buttons(usually power and volume button simultaneously) and it screenshots everything on screen as they seemed(including keyboard, videoview etc.). Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Read somewhere on the forums about another way: -

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
```

You can try that out. Don't know if it works or not, just saved it for a rainy day :P.

EDIT:

Found the link to the post - [How to take a screenshots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741302/how-to-take-a-screenshots)

User says, screenshots work for him. I think this should suit your requirement.

Comment: su is superuser does this need rooting on device?

Comment: yes it does. :D. But i don't think there is another way to get the screenshot of the phone from an app. The most he can do is get the screenshot he is getting right now.

Comment: if he is testing on emulator i guess it already rooted. But it is not good to release your app asking users to root their device. Any how its a suggestion. I leave it to the OP to decide. Any way i got to learn something new from the link posted.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is no way to get screenshot from screen of a device that `is not rooted`.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296804/1043882),[CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) says:

> If you mean "screenshot of somebody else's activity", that is not
>   supported, for obvious ***privacy and security reasons***.

Although you can get screenshot of emulator when your App is running!

Edit:

But there exists a library that is called `ASL`(Android Screenshot Library):

> Android Screenshot Library (ASL) enables to programmatically capture
>   screenshots from Android devices without requirement of having root
>   access privileges. Instead, ASL utilizes a native service running in
>   the background, started via the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) once per
>   device boot.

I did not try it,but you can see more details in about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/).